# bash nested case syntax and ;; terminators

Tags: bash

Have I got enough (or perhaps too many) `;;` terminators in this bash script containing nested `case`'s?

```
case "$1" in
OK)
    # Nothing needs done
    echo -n "OK:1" ;;

CRITICAL)

    case "$2" in
    SOFT)
        case "$3" in
        1|2) 
            soft_reset_pool.sh ;;
        esac ;;

    HARD)
        case "$3" in
        1|2)
            hard_reset_pool.sh ;;

        3|4)
            hard_reset_service ;;

        esac ;;
    esac ;;      
esac
```

It's been a few years since I did any bash in anger.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's easier to keep track if you use sensible indentation on the `;;`s.

```
case "$1" in
OK)
    # Nothing needs done
    echo -n "OK:1"
    ;;

CRITICAL)

    case "$2" in
    SOFT)
        case "$3" in
        1|2) 
            soft_reset_pool.sh
            ;;
        esac
        ;;

    HARD)
        case "$3" in
        1|2)
            hard_reset_pool.sh
            ;;

        3|4)
            hard_reset_service
            ;;

        esac
        ;;
    esac
    ;;
esac
```

They match up fine, every `case` *label*`)` having a terminating `;;`

That said, sometimes it's easier and/or clearer to collapse everything into a non-nested `case`:

```
case "$1:$2:$3" in

OK:*)
    # Nothing needs done
    echo -n "OK:1"
    ;;

CRITICAL:SOFT:[12])
    soft_reset_pool.sh
    ;;

CRITICAL:HARD:[12])
    hard_reset_pool.sh
    ;;

CRITICAL:HARD:[34])
    hard_reset_service
    ;;

esac
```

Comment: Collapsing the case statement was the best idea, in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to deal with multiple pattern strings :

Imagine $3 is a string.

```
...
CRITICAL:HARD:@("A"|"B"|"C"))
...
```

In Bash you need to add the following on the script :

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Thanks to [Hauke Laging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/32191/hauke-laging) for the tip.