# Is it possible to have a case within a case, like if within a if

Tags: case

Is it possible to have a case within a case, I have seen examples of people using many ifs

```
if ($check1=1);then
    if ($check2=2);then
        if($check3=3);then
        fi
    fi
fi
```

I'm not sure how do i put this example into the case within a case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Check out [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15216/bash-nested-case-syntax-and-terminators).  They work the same way as nested ifs - just watch your `;;` operators.

Comment: Linking to a another answer on this site doesn't constitute an (original) answer...

Comment: So, do I just put it in the comments to Zac's question?

Comment: Ordinarily, yes. But it has already been marked as a dupe, so the point is made.

Comment: wow, how is this a dupe, i searched on this site and no results were found, the link provided by @ice13berg has a different title. And thanks once again.