# Parsing arguments with nested case statements

Tags: bash

I am trying to build a program with 2 modes, each mode takes a different set of arguments. I have tried to implement nested case statements as described by @geekosaur in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15216/bash-nested-case-syntax-and-terminators?newreg=47472730527f44808d409502474ab1d9), with `case "$1"` going through modes and `case "$2"` going through arguments.

I have a general `--help` option for the program describing the modes which are available, and a separate `--help` for each mode describing the arguments.

If I run:

`./program.sh --help` works

`./program.sh mode1 --help` works

`./program.sh mode1 --unknown` works (it correctly catches the unknown option and calls the usage function for mode1)

However:

`./program.sh mode1 --option1 file`

`ERROR: unknown parameter file`

I.e., it is recognizing "file" as a parameter instead of a value for key "option1".

How can I make this work? Am I messing up with my "shifts", or do I need nested loops?

(Only showing "mode1" in the code below for simplicity)

```
#!/bin/bash

usage_general() {
    echo "Usage: ProgramName [modes]"
    echo ""
    printf "%-10s %s\n" "mode1" "Run subprogram 1."
    printf "%-10s %s\n" "mode2" "Run subprogram 2."
}

usage_mode1() {
    echo "Usage: ProgramName mode1 [options]"
    echo ""
    printf "%-10s %s\n" "-1 | --option1" "Arg 1 for mode1"
    printf "%-10s %s\n" "-2 | --option2" "Arg 2 for mode1."
}


while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
    case "$1" in
    -h | --help)
        usage_general
        exit
        ;;

    mode1)

        case "$2" in
        -h | --help)
            usage_mode1
            exit
            ;;
        -1 | --option1)
            val1="$3"
            shift 2
            ;;
        -2 | --option2)
            val2="$3"
            shift 2
            ;;
        *)
            echo "ERROR: unknown parameter $2"
            usage_mode1
            exit 1
            ;;
        esac
        ;;

    *)
        echo "ERROR: unknown parameter $1"
        usage_general
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `shift 2` in the inner `case`, you shift off `$1` and `$2`, but not `$3`, the filename.

You would need to do a separate loop for parsing the options to the `mode1` and `mode2` sub command.

Assuming that when a sub command is found in the command line argument of the script, the rest of the options and option-arguments belongs to that sub command, you could split up the parsing like so:

```bash
run_mode1 () {
    while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
        case "$1" in
        -h | --help)
            usage_mode1
            exit
            ;;
        -1 | --option1)
            val1="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        -2 | --option2)
            val2="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        *)
            echo "ERROR: unknown parameter $1"
            usage_mode1
            exit 1
            ;;
        esac
    done

    # code for actually running mode1 goes here
}

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
    case "$1" in
    -h | --help)
        usage_general
        exit
        ;;

    mode1)
        shift
        run_mode1 "$@"
        break
        ;;

    *)
        echo "ERROR: unknown parameter $1"
        usage_general
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Here, we run a shell function as soon as we encounter `mode1` amongst the command line arguments.  That function takes care of parsing the rest of the argument list.

This would obviously only work in the specific circumstance that *all* options to *the script* (not to a sub command) occurs *before* any given sub command on the command line, and that there may only be a single sub command with options given in any one invocation of the script.

It would not be impossible to implement the command line parsing in such a way that the script would be able to accept two or more sub commands with options at once, as in

```
./script.sh ...options... mode1 ...options... mode2 ...options...
```

but I'll leave that for now.

Comment: Thank you. In your first approach, it works for `./program.sh mode1 --option1 file`. However, if I attempt to use both --option1 and --option2 as in `./program.sh mode1 --option1 file1 --option2 file2`, I get ERROR: unknown parameter --option2.

Comment: @VitorRezendedaCostaAguiar Ah, yes. That's actually a case where the second approach will work for you.  If _all_ of the options after `mode1` are for that mode, parsing them in a separate shell function may be what you want to do.  Alternatively do an inner loop inside the `case` statement. I'm on an awkward machine at the moment and can't do testing. I'll come back to this tomorrow (it's midnight).

Comment: Thank you very much. The second approach seems to work great, and I agree that it is nicer. I tried it with a mode2 as well, and it works.

Comment: Another problem which I ran into is the following. In the command `./program.sh mode1 --option1 file1 --option2 file2`, if user doesn't give a value for --option1 (e.g., `./program.sh mode1 --option1 --option2 file2`), I get `ERROR: unknown parameter file2`.  In this case, I cannot test if --option1 value is empty, because it takes "--option2" as its value! How can I avoid that please? @Kusalananda

Comment: @VitorRezendedaCostaAguiar Take `sed` as an example of a standard tool that also takes a filename as an argument (to its `-f` option).  If you forget to give it a filename and follow up with `-e` (for an expression), you get `sed: -e: so such file or directory`. Taking this as the pattern to follow, you should check for the existence of the argument to both `--option1` and `--option2` immediately and give the appropriate error message if the given name does not exist (I would use `if [ ! -e "$argument" ]; then ...error message and exit 1...; fi`).